# Can a disk be defined with a discrete metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:\rho_d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$? Say for $\epsilon<1$, the disk doesn't exist.

Edit: Elaborating on the question. Can you call it a disk if it is not the euclidean metric?

Comment: @Rahul 0. So are you saying the radius needs to be greater than 0?

Comment: $D$ defined like that is no disk. It has no centerpoint.

Comment: Your definition of the disc should be $D_{x,\epsilon}=\{y\in\Bbb{R}, \rho_d(x,y)\lt\epsilon\}$ and when $\epsilon\lt 1$ the disc is limited to its center $x$

Comment: Every disk contains its centerpoint and the disk can also be a singleton.

Comment: In any metric space $(X,d)$ the set $\{x:d(x,y)<r\}$ is called the open disk with center $y$ and radius $r$. Here $r>0$ and $y\in X$. The disk always exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **open disc** $D_\epsilon(x)$ around $x$ with radius $\epsilon>0$ in e.g. $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined to be $$D_\epsilon(x):=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^2|d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$$

In case $d$ is the discrete metric this means you have for all $x,y$

$$d(x,x) = 0$$

$$d(x,y) = 1 \text{ if } x\neq y$$

In case $\epsilon < 1$ you have $$D_\epsilon(x) = \{x\}$$ since all $y\neq x$ have $d(x,y)=1$ and are thereby not in $D_\epsilon(x)$.